# WAMPServer 2.2 PHP_CURL returning boolean false works fine in Prod

Tags: php, curl, wamp, wampserver

Running WAMP 2.2

PHP 5.4.3
JQuery 2.10

Curl Request in Prod gives Status 200 and JSON response

Curl Request in WAMP gives Status 0 and boolean false as a response.

It's the same exact code. Help?!

curl enabled in php.ini

php.ini info:

```
cURL support    enabled
cURL Information    7.25.0
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Figured out the error I was getting was:
SSL certificate problem, verify that the CA cert is OK.

But I'm not getting it on my Linux server, is there a way to ignore those in the ini level instead of adding the following?

```
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
```

UPDATE:

Fixed it by adding the following to my php.ini file

```
curl.cainfo = "C:/wamp/cert/cacert.pem"
```